# How to make mypy ignore no-untyped-def error on internal (private) methods

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'm using mypy with `disallow-untyped-defs` flag so it complains when I create a method that doesn't have type annotation on parameters or return (`error: Function is missing a type annotation  [no-untyped-def]`).

This is usually what I want. I want to make sure all public methods have type annotations, but I don't want to be strict on the internal methods (methods starting with one or two leading underscore). How can I make mypy ignore internal methods?

Example:

```py
def foo(a, b):
  return a + b

def _bar(a, b):
  return a + b

def __baz(a, b):
  return a + b
```

`mypy --disallow-untyped-defs --check-untyped-defs <module_name>`

Current output: [no-untyped-def] missing type annotation error on all three methods.

Desired output: error on only `foo` method.

Comment: There is no such configuration option. I imagine there could be an easy solution with `awk` or any other text processing utility to remove the undesired errors and set exit code if any lines were still emitted, but I must warn you that it's very bad idea for typechecking your own code - you effectively have a ton of `Any` types that can hide many errors.

Comment: You can write a mypy plugin which does this. A better alternative, if the purpose is to hide non-public members, is to generate a `.pyi` stub file with only the public members exposed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `# type: ignore[no-untyped-def]`

In your example:

```py
def foo(a, b):
  return a + b

def _bar(a, b): # type: ignore[no-untyped-def]
  return a + b

def __baz(a, b): # type: ignore[no-untyped-def]
  return a + b
```

Comment: Hi, i'm looking for setting it in a project level so that i don't need to suppress it every time a new private method is written. However, as I understand from the comments, there's no easy way to do it.

Comment: Your case seems to be an unusual/quite particular one.

As a workaround, I would evaluate writing a python script to go over all the *.py in your project, looking for lines starting with `def_` or `def__` and add  `# type: ignore[no-untyped-def]` in the end. This script would run as a custom pre-commit hook in your project.

Anyway, don't forget [Explicit is better than implicit](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python) :)